# Android Bitmap for Performance

Tags: android, bitmap

I have this

```
    Bitmap appWidgetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(availableWidth, availableHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(appWidgetBitmap);
```

And in the log console I see this

```
"dalvikvm-heap Grow heap (frag case) to......byte allocation
```

How can I  make Bitmap with the lowest resources possible?
I saw something on `BitmapFactory`, but how to do it because the code above is `createBitmap`, not from resources.

Comment: This is what you need. http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html .

Answer (score 1):

Use below methods for resizing the image as aspect ratio:

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and
        // keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res,
        int resId, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
            reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    // BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

     return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options), reqWidth,
            reqHeight, true);
}
```

Then decode your image into bitmap format and set into the Canvas:

```
 Bitmap src = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.ic_bg_box, imgWidth, imgHeight);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(src);
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks. Should be this way.

Comment: Hi, anyway I don't have the resource. You see my code is only create a bitmap then put it into Canvas. But your code is to decode Bitmap from a resource.